# Access current user in entity lifecycle callback

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

In my doctrine entity I have a lifecycle callback that needs access to the currently logged in user (something like `TokenStorage`).

Can I stick to the lifecycle callback or do I have to switch to an event listener where the token storage is injected?

```
/** @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks() */
class Report {
    /** @ORM\PrePersist */
    public function onPrePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = new \DateTime();
        $this->lastUpdatedBy = ???->getToken()->getUser(); // <-----
    }
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this won't work and it's also not a good practice to put that logic into the entity. Event listener would be a much better choice.

Comment: When you find a correct place you can inject `use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;` into your class and access Token and User from it. Don't do it where you are currently trying to do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the good way to do this is to use the doctrine event listener:

file service.yml

```
    services:
         my_report_listener :
          class : App\EventListener\ReportListner
          arguments: ['@security.token_storage']
          tags:
             - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: prePersist }
```

your event listener class :

```
    class ReportListner {

      private $tokenStorage;

      public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
      {
         $this->tokenStorage= $tokenStorage;
      }

      public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
      {
        $entity = $args->getObject();
        if($entity instanceof Report){
         $current_user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: No need for the `arguments` part in services config if you use the default Symfony 4 configuration.